# Mouse capture release issue using SilverlightTookit control ListBoxDragDropTarget

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have implemented drag and drop functionality using ListBoxDragDropTarget control of SilverlightToolkit in Silverlight 5.

Drag and drop functionality is working fine but some time when I clicked any item from ListBox, the item is sticks with mouse and after selecting I moving mouse around it, Item is dragging around with mouse pointer though I have release MouseLeftButton.

Can anyone help me about this issue, this issue is generating randomly, So I am unable to take the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Silverlight, i have suffered with this for a while. I think it's to do with the mouse down / mouse up events firing out of sequence.

I did some research and located a work item which is supposed to fix this problem. (At least for some people)

I have not had time to implement it myself yet - so cannot say if it works or not.

But here it is, worth a try!

[ListBoxDragDropTarget misses mouse up event occasionally](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/5930)

Comment: Thanks @DNKROZ for your reply, I have already tried your option and definitely it's good option and I can say it has solved my issue 70% but still it's not working for some time... :(

Comment: Yep same for me, it may be a bug we just have to live with. I would be very interested to know if anyone has fixed this & the method that they used.